# Solana Web3js Connection object socket timeout

Tags: transaction

I have a simple websocket set up to listen to logs. It works, but then when I try to send over the transaction signature to a connection object to parse the instructions from it, it errors out after 30 minutes or so like this:

```
Error fetching transaction: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ClientBrowser.callServer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:4901:17) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6625:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6583:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6614:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

Here is the code snippet that I am trying to parse it in:

```
async function fetchTransactionInfo(txHash) {
  let retryAttempts = 5;
  let transaction;

  while (retryAttempts > 0) {
    try {
      const connection = new Connection(HTTP_ENDPOINT, {
        httpAgent: false,
        confirmTransactionInitialTimeout: 240000
      });
      transaction = await connection.getParsedTransaction(txHash, {
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
        finalized: true
      });
      if (transaction) {
        break; // If the transaction is fetched successfully, exit the loop
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching transaction:', txHash + ' ' + error);
      retryAttempts--;
      if (retryAttempts === 0) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch transaction after retries:', txHash);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch transaction after retries: ' + txHash);
      }
      console.log(`Retrying... attempts left: ${retryAttempts}`);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)); // Wait for 10 seconds before retrying
    }
  }

  if (!transaction) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch transaction:', txHash);
    return {};
  }
}
... rest of logic
```

This fetchTransactionInfo function is basically being called every few minutes or so with a different transaction signature by my code. It's fine as a standalone script, but when I leave this running on a server for a while it starts giving the UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT error. So I was wondering if anyone had similar issues and how did they resolve them?

For additional context, I have tried different kinds of connection configs, e.g. Connection(HTTP_ENDPOINT), Connection(HTTP_ENDPOINT, {httpAgent: false}), etc. But they don't really show much of a difference. Would appreciate any guidance on this matter!

In addition, I have tried exponential backoffs with my retries but they don't change the outcome, even if I throw in different RPC url's for each attempt at creating a new Connection object.

Comment: Are you using the public solana endpoints? These have heavy rate limits on socket connections.

Comment: I have used both public and private solana endpoints and these still give the same issues. It's not really a rate limit issue because I only pass transactions to be parsed like once every 5 minutes?